# Как правильно: Доставка товара потребителю или к потребителю?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: **Доставка** товара **потребителю** или **к потребителю**? Если оба варианта допустимы, то есть ли существенная разница в смыслах?

Answer (score 1):

Кому? Потребителю

Куда? К потребителю (домой, на работу)